# SharePoint: Programmatically moving pages and subsites on the current navigation menu

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know how to programmatically move/order the pages and subsites that appear in the **Current Navigation** when you have the **Include subsites** and **include pages** options ticked/enabled?

### Background

I have written a class (in c#) which imports content into a new SharePoint site. The newly created subsites and pages all show on the Current Navigation menu as expected, but in the order they were created (I assume). I need to manually sort the pages on the menu so that they appear in the same order as the existing non-SharePoint site.

### Issue

The PublishingWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNodes collection does not contain any SPNavigationNode items for the pages and subsites that are automatically displayed on the Current Navigation menu, so I can't use this collection.

I know that to hide a particular page from the menu, you have to update a web property as follows:

```
web.AllProperties["__CurrentNavigationExcludes"] += page.UniqueId.ToString() + ";";
web.Update();
```

Is there something similar I can use to order the pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Ordering to manual

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.orderingmethod.aspx

Check out the follow up article on this:  http://www.thekickboard.com/archive/2010/09/01/programmatically-setting-navigation-order-in-a-moss-publishing-site.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is this sort of what you are looking for:

http://www.thekickboard.com/archive/2010/09/01/programmatically-setting-navigation-order-in-a-moss-publishing-site.aspx